# Is "sleeveless vest" redundant?

Tags: american-english, terminology, phrase-usage, redundancy

I had always thought a vest implied a sleeveless garment of clothing, but I find several instances of the phrase "sleeveless vest."  Isn't that redundant and is there any reputable, somewhat definitive resource that supports this view (or at least discusses the usage of it)?

Comment: What we AmEs call a *vest*, BrEs call a *waistcoat*. What BrEs call a *vest*, we AmEs call an *undershirt*. So if a BrE speaker describes something as a *sleeveless vest*, we AmEs might call that a [*wife-beater*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeveless_shirt#/media/File:Man_in_A_shirt_at_the_Brooklyn_Book_Festival.jpg) (or, more technically, an "*A shirt*").

Comment: Please say whether you want to know about British or American English.

Comment: And *search* "long-sleeved vest," or "thermal underwear" to see what "sleeveless vest" is trying to distinguish itself from.

Comment: The "wife-beater" is also know as a "dago tee" (at least here in the US).

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'd never heard that! In fact, I don't think I've heard *dago* at all, outside of old movies.

Comment: I think it was an expression here in the Chicago area - possibly before "wife beater" - but I'd have to research that to verify it.

Comment: @DanBron Calling slim-shouldered sleeveless t-shirts *wife-beaters* — rather than *tank-tops* or *singlets* — might come off as urban ghetto jargon. That may be good or it may be bad: it all depends what one is trying to convey or imply. I have yet to see such a label on the packaging for underwear sold in pedestrian department stores to a broad audience.

Comment: @tchrist Here in NYC, anyway, *tank-top* is reserved (primarily) for a woman's garment. And I've never heard of "singlets".  I guess I don't know what the package reads; I don't wear these kinds of t-shirts (and if I did, I imagine they're a commodity purchase, so I wouldn't read the label, any more than I read the label on toilet paper).

Comment: @DanBron Honestly, that it might be sex-linked for some speakers never occurred to me, since in the western Great Lakes region (MN, WI, MI, IL), *tank-top* is the normal word for it no matter the gender wearing it.  I think the term is in broader usage than that, since it is also usedout West. On the other hand, *singlet* is common in Canada, such as in Vancouver for example.

Comment: Northern British English -  A sleeveless undershirt is a vest. A tanktop is a knighted jumper with no sleeves.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Where are you from?  I never heard "dago tee", but "Guinea tee" was around for generations before "wife beater" or, "beater", for short.  (I'm descended from NY Italians who got here in 1900.)

Comment: The technical term for the garment which, along with jacket (or, coat) and trousers comprises a classic, three-piece suit, is "waistcoat". In the US we usually call this piece a "vest", but this terminology will not serve if one is communicating to non-Americans.

Comment: @DanBron To answer Dan Bron's question, I suppose I was primarily interested in American English when I posed the question, but I didn't necessarily want to limit myself to just American English.

Comment: I realize now, after reading through the posts that it appears the notion of what a vest is can vary from person to person.  For starters, I've never known anyone who considered a tank top or wife beater to be a vest.  The vests I am familiar with come with a zipper or a set of buttons.

Comment: Truth be told, I was really just trying to translate from one language into another when I realized that the foreign phrase I was translating from was actually "sleeveless" + "vest."  I was surprised even more, however, when I searched for images using those same two words in English and more than half a million results were returned for it.  I then wondered whether I should use what seems to me to be redundant or what so many appear to be using.  If I wanted to buck what appeared to be a trend, I thought it might be good to at least consult or review something of substance.

Comment: @Hugh I did do a search of images for several different combinations of words that might lead me to images of sleeved vests, but what few were produced from those searches were hardly what I would consider a vest.  Nevertheless, I can envision in my mind what a vest with sleeves might look like, but when I see a definition that reads "a sleeveless, close-fitting waist-length garment worn over a shirt, typically having no collar and buttoning down the front" in more than one dictionary, I just have to wonder how the disconnect between definition and usage came about.

Comment: @LisaBeck It's a regional difference, usually. What regions are the dictionary definitions from?

Comment: You know, everything you write contains redundancies.

Answer (score 2):

In Italy we normally wear a "canottiera" (white and sleeveless)(which I call  "cannottiera", as we do in Tuscany and I think also around Rome), or a "maglietta della pelle" (simple white t shirt, with short sleeves). They are both "vests" in English (Free Dictionary Online:vest1 [vɛst] n (Brit) (with sleeves) → maglia intima; (sleeveless) → canottiera).                   Something similar is done in other Countries and that is one reason why sometimes you must use the words "sleeveless vest" to better explain the garment you are looking for (Canottiera o similar).

Comment: Thank you for your addition, alsa.  I do see now that a dictionary reference includes the British meaning -- an undershirt.  I hadn't seen that elsewhere and now some of the other comments made in this thread make much more sense.  As a speaker of American English, I think I'm going to go with "vest" for something without sleeves and avoid the compulsion to translate word-for-word/literally.  Sometimes it is best to keep it simple.  Nevertheless, I appreciate all the contributions to this question.  If I'm ever outside the US, I'll know that a "vest" might not be what I think it is.